# I can't acces int[] in TreeMap

Tags: java, arrays, list

i have a list of objects:

```
static List table_rows = new ArrayList();
```

Which i want to fill with TreeMaps, which consist of a String and an Integer array object:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < observation_files.length; i++) {
        TreeMap<String, Integer[]> tm = new TreeMap<String, Integer[]>();
        Integer[] cells = new Integer[observation_files.length];
        for (int x = 0; x < cells.length; x++) {
            cells[x] = 0;
        }
        tm.put("model" + i, cells);
        table_rows.add(tm);
    }
```

now i want to access the int array like so:

```
        table_rows.get(0).get("model1")[0] = 2;
```

but eclipse does not let me do this and gives me this error:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    The method get(String) is undefined for the type Object
    Syntax error on token ".", Identifier expected after this token

        at HmmPipeline.main(HmmPipeline.java:102)
```

Code hinting or completion gives me nothing to work with, what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raw `ArrayList.get()` returns type `Object`. If you want it to return `TreeMap<String, Integer[]>`, you should declare your list as:

```
static List<TreeMap<String, Integer[]>> table_rows = new ArrayList<TreeMap<String, Integer[]>>();
```

If you use an IDE like Eclipse, it's a good idea to set your code compilation options to show a warning when you're using raw (unparameterised) types. Although it should've flagged your code up as invalid anyway.

As an aside, what you're trying to do isn't a very effective way of storing what's basically a two-dimensional square array.

Comment: I know, but i need to be able to address the cells based on a string and not an index number. I actually ended up having rows of TreeMaps wich where <String, TreeMap> in itself.

Answer (score 1):

You need to either cast `table_rows.get(0)` to `(TreeMap<String, Integer[]>)` or define that in the `table_rows` declaration:

```
static List<TreeMap<String, Integer[]>> table_rows = new ArrayList<TreeMap<String, Integer[]>>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
static List<TreeMap<String, Integer[]>> table_rows = new ArrayList<TreeMap<String, Integer[]>>();
```

Or, you would need a cast as follows:

```
((TreeMap<String, Integer[]>)table_rows.get(0)).get("model1")[0] = 2;
```

---

Also, depending the functionalities of your interest, you could refer to your `TreeMap` using the reference of one of following interface types -

- `Map<K,V>`
- `NavigableMap<K,V>`
- `SortedMap<K,V>`

Answer (score 0):

**1.** You will need to declare the type of ArrayList you want to use.

```
static List<TreeMap<String, Integer[]>> table_rows = new ArrayList<TreeMap<String, Integer[]>>();
```

**2.** Iterate over a Map like this..

```
for (Map.EntrySet(String, Integer) temp : tm.entrySet()){

        // use getKey(), getValue() and do whatever u want.

       }
```